# cannot access AWS EKS nginx ingress created nlb from a busybox pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, nlb

can anyone help with AWS EKS with the nginx-ingress issue, my EKS is on the private subnet and I have installed nginx-ingress on top of it as an ingress controller after that I have deployed a sample angular application and created service and ingress, I have able to do a curl from the ingress-controller pod with ingress name but when I'm trying to do a curl with elb/alb created by ingress is not working from a busybox pod, can anyone help me on this, please
I have deployed my nginx-ingress from the [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.40.2/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml)
I have checked a couple of stack overflow articles and questions, but I didn't find the solution, I see a couple of people also looking for the same solution on other platforms, if someone answers this, it will help other people also

Comment: you can all have different issues. what is "doesn't work?" timeout?

Comment: @suren I'm seeing timeout with load balancer URL and when I do a curl from the ingress controller pod with ingress name it is working

Comment: I believe it's because of the private subnet. try hitting the `nodePort` that points to the Ingress Controller from within other pod.

Comment: @KNCK, please attach your yaml files to the question. Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak 1.19 is the kubernetes version

Comment: @KNCK, please attach your yaml files to the question.

Comment: the issue is resolved, it's because of the wrong configuration in ingress configuration, after installing the ingress again, it was working